# Declare PrintWriter outside method

Tags: java

I need to declare PrintWriter outside the method openLog so I can access it from multiple methods, because this way I can only access PrintWriter ONLY when it is inside one method, but then I can't access it from other methods!

```
package com.donemanuel.DSDK;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class LogKit {
    void openLog() throws IOException{

    Date ltm = new Date( );
    SimpleDateFormat lt = new SimpleDateFormat ("'['dd.MM hh:mm:ss a']: '");
    final String logtm = lt.format(ltm);
    PrintWriter logd = new PrintWriter("res/LOGTIME_"+logtm, "UTF-8");

    String prefix = "[Logger]:";

    logd.println(prefix + "DSDK Logger opened!"); 

    logd.println("----------xXx----------");
    logd.flush();

}
void custommessage(String logmsg){
    logd.println(logmsg); //I want to print custom messages with my API, but log is declared in another void so thats the problem.
    //If i would declare logd (printwriter) outside a void it would give me an error!
}
}
```

Comment: google java class variables

Comment: Yes , so what exactly you want from SO ?

Comment: Do you mean 'method' by 'void' ?

Comment: Please first learn some basic Java terms. I think you mean method with `void`...

Comment: Yes, method... I want the PrintWriter logd = new... to be above void openLog()... BUT that throws me an error with no suggestions!

Comment: Here, I made it easier for you: http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html

Comment: @donemanuel If you're encountering an error, it is borderling **essential** that you include details of that error in your question.  Without that, all anyone can do is guess (and it sounds like what you're doing *should* work, so the error's even more important).

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Default constructor cannot handle exception type FileNotFoundException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor
 Default constructor cannot handle exception type UnsupportedEncodingException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor

 at com.donemanuel.DSDK.LogKit.<init>(LogKit.java:16)
 at com.donemanuel.DSDK.Console.<init>(Console.java:13)
 at com.donemanuel.DSDK.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:9)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

make changes in your code as follows

```
package com.donemanuel.DSDK;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class LogKit {
 PrintWriter logd ;
void openLog() throws IOException{

Date ltm = new Date( );
SimpleDateFormat lt = new SimpleDateFormat ("'['dd.MM hh:mm:ss a']: '");
final String logtm = lt.format(ltm);
logd = new PrintWriter("res/LOGTIME_"+logtm, "UTF-8");

String prefix = "[Logger]:";

logd.println(prefix + "DSDK Logger opened!"); 

logd.println("----------xXx----------");
logd.flush();

}
void custommessage(String logmsg)  throws IOException{
logd.println(logmsg); //I want to print custom messages with my API, but log is declared in another void so thats the problem.
//If i would declare logd (printwriter) outside a void it would give me an error!
}
}
```

Comment: Thats what I tought would help me, but it throws an error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Default constructor cannot handle exception type FileNotFoundException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor
 Default constructor cannot handle exception type UnsupportedEncodingException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor

 at com.donemanuel.DSDK.LogKit.<init>(LogKit.java:15)
 at com.donemanuel.DSDK.Console.<init>(Console.java:13)
 at com.donemanuel.DSDK.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:9)

Comment: wait i ll make changes and try it.

Comment: now try this i made changes in it.

Comment: @donemanuel is it working now?

Comment: yes, but i dont get it, I did SAME thing before I asked this, and I got an error... I copied your code in and it works ;) **Thank you**

Comment: may be some minor issues has left.

Answer (score 0):

In java you can declare "variables" (called "attributes" or "fields") of a class in this way:

```
public class YourClass {
  PrintWriter logd = new PrintWriter("path/file", "UTF-8");


  void openLog() throws IOException{
     //your code that uses "logd" here
  }

  void custommessage(String logmsg){
     //your other code that uses "logd" here
  }
}
```

For more informations about *initialization* of attributes of a class and class *constructors* try to use google with those keyword.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean about "the void" ?

In the code above, you can't access the logd variable from "custommessage(String)" method because there's no variable with this name in the scope.
If you problem is to access to variable with the same name that you have defined into "openLog()" method, just create a new attribute. Set this attribute with the object that is referenced by the logd variable and then use this attribute into "custommessage(String)".

Samples:

```
public class AttributeSample {
  private Object myAttribute = null;

  public void init() {
    myAttribute = new Object();
  }

  public void doSomething() {
    if (myAttribute != null) {
      System.out.println(myAttribute);
    } else {
      throw new RuntimException("Oups ! You must call init() before.");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your case, is that you are trying to initialise a field in a way that might throw an exception.  And you need to provide some context about how this exception might be handled.

If it weren't for the exception, you could initialise fields simply, for example:

```
public class LogKit {
    private int i = 0; // this initialises fine

    void openLog() {
        ...
    }
}
```

However, the constructor of `PrintWriter` throws an exception.  And so the code that runs this must either catch the exception, or declare it to be thrown.  Currently you're creating the PrintWriter in your `openLog` method, and this method declares `throws IOException`, so the compiler is happy.  But when you move it out there is no such clause.

Fields with initialisers are actually run inside the (auto-generated) constructor.  The example I gave above is actually identical to:

```
public class LogKit {
    private int i;

    public LogKit() {
        i = 0;
    }

    void openLog() {
        ...
    }
}
```

and so one way to resolve this is to declare the constructor yourself, which lets you specify that it might throw an exception:

```
public class LogKit {
    PrintWriter logd;

    public LogKit() throws IOException {
        Date ltm = new Date( );
        SimpleDateFormat lt = new SimpleDateFormat ("'['dd.MM hh:mm:ss a']: '");
        logd = new PrintWriter("res/LOGTIME_"+logtm, "UTF-8");
    }
}
```

This is probably the best approach - by creating the writer in the constructor, it is guaranteed to be defined for the whole lifetime of the class.

If, for some reason, you can't deal with the constructor throwing an exception, then you'll need to defer the creation of the field until later.  In this case, every bit of code that refers to `logd` will have to bear in mind that it might be `null` if it hasn't been assigned yet.  What should `custommessage` do if it's called before `openLog`?  You'll need to think about different states of the class, which is why this is more complex.  But in some cases this "lifecycle" approach is the only viable one.

Comment: `custommessage` has no way of being called before `openlog` because `openlog` is called in main class on start of the program! In case it gets called before I have ErrorKit that will pop up error with all details I would need to fix the problem! Also this `ErrorKit``LogKit``SoundKit` is just a part of my SDK, Im doing this to help my friends learn Java, and making them easier to call sounds, errors, logs, console... and such

Comment: @donemanuel - Of course, `custommessage` can't be called before `openlog` *at the moment*.  But a year down the line, when your `LogKit` gets used in different places by different bits of code - and you're using some abstracted set-up mechanism - will this definitely still be true?  It is always possible for callers to use your classes in the "wrong" way, and you need to think about what to do in these cases, even if it's just as simple as "I'll add documentation saying you shouldn't do this, and let it fail with a `NullPointerException` if someone does".